# Process synchronization in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, semaphore, synchronization

I try to synchronize multiple processes by using semaphores. I thought instead of creating a function for each process, it might be possible in a more generic way,  with a single function and some arguments for the dependencies:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import *

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self._semaphores = [Semaphore(0)]*(size + 1)

    def run(self, name, acquire, release):
        for i in acquire:
            self._semaphores[i].acquire()

            print('Running', name)

        for i in release:
            self._semaphores[i].release()
```

In this case I've got five processes. The first starts first, the second and third after the first, the fourth after the second and third, and the fifth after the fourth.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker = Worker(5)
    Process(target=worker.run, args=('5', [5], [])).start()
    Process(target=worker.run, args=('4', [4,4], [5])).start()
    Process(target=worker.run, args=('3', [3], [4])).start()
    Process(target=worker.run, args=('2', [2], [4])).start()
    Process(target=worker.run, args=('1', [], [2,3])).start()
```

The expected output would be:

```
Running 1
Running 2
Running 3
Running 4
Running 5
```

But the synchronization doesn't work as expected. The execution is random including deadlocks. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Semaphore(0)]*(size + 1)` creates a list with `size + 1` references to a *single* `Semaphore` object. You need to make different instances of that class:

```
self._semaphores = [Semaphore(0) for _ in range(size + 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is absolutely correct! But there is one little thing I don't get. The fixed version doesn't force the expected order. So the output is still random but without deadlocks on a Windows system. Any idea?

Comment: @witrin: I'm not entirely sure why you need the semaphores. Why don't you create a process pool and use `pool.map_sync` to get the results back in order?

Comment: Because it is part of an exercise that requires the use of semaphores.

Comment: It seems, that the fixed code doesn't work on Windows, on Linux there are no problems anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of your print is incorrect which prevents ('Running', '1').  After this is fixed, 1 prints, followed by 2 and 3 intermixed, followed by 4, then 5.  2 and 3 are mixed because they are kicked off together, so operation is as expected.